# Clone Azure Test Plan to new area path using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a powershell script that clones my test plans - I am using Azure 2019 so the function is not built in. My script works, but only clones plans to the same area path. I would like to be able to clone to a new area path. For example, in the image below, under Test Plans, I want to clone 'TestPlan1.7' in MyTests\Version1.7 to 'NewTestPlan' in MyTests\Version1.8. The code I use currently creates the new test plan as it clones, but either that or manually creating a new one is an option. Also, I cannot download/ install any addons or mods to azure, so those aren't a solution for me. Thanks for any help!
Here is my current code snippet to clone. I have the variables listed in my script, but don't think they're needed for this.

EDIT: I tried your answer Sunny (and also just realized I can edit my own question to add stuff) Here is my entire code, along with the error. The variables have been changed for obvious reasons, but the structure is the same. The line number the error gave is the one that starts with 'Invoke-WebRequest'

```
$organization = "myOrg"    
$PAT = "MyAzurePAT"
$myBaseUrl = "myAzureUrl"
$project = "myTests"   
$planId = "123456"   
$suiteId = "123457"   
$cloneTo = "NewtestPlan"

$authorization = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$PAT"))
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Accept-Charset", 'UTF-8')
$headers.Add('Content-Type','Application/Json')
$headers.Add('Authorization',"Basic $authorization")

$postParams=@"
{
  "destinationTestPlan": {
    "name": "$cloneTo",
    "Project": {
      "Name": "$project"
    }
  },
  "options": {
    "copyAncestorHierarchy": true,
    "copyAllSuites": true,
    "overrideParameters": {
    "System.AreaPath": "myTests\Version1.8",
    "System.IterationPath": "NewtestPlan"
    }
  },
  "suiteIds": [  
    $suiteId
  ]
}
"@

$apiUrl = "$myBaseUrl/$organization/$project/_apis/test/Plans/$planId/cloneoperation?api-version=5.0-preview.2"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $postParams |  Select-Object -Expand StatusDescription

<#Error
Invoke-WebRequest : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be 
null.\r\nParameter name: cloneRequestBody","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At [locationRemoved]\testPlanCloneTool.ps1:39 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
#>
```

[image: Azure screen snip]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the "overrideParameters" under "options"?

```
$postParams=@"
{
  "destinationTestPlan": {
    "name": "$cloneTo",
    "Project": {
      "Name": "$project"
    }
  },
  "options": {
    "copyAncestorHierarchy": true,
    "copyAllSuites": true,
    "overrideParameters": {
     "System.AreaPath": "MyTests\Version1.8",
      "System.IterationPath": "NewTestPlan"
    }
  },
  "suiteIds": [  
    $sourceSuiteId,
   ]
}
"@
```

MS Docs Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/clone%20operation/clone%20test%20plan?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#cloneoptions

Comment: I did, and got a  long error (too long to post in the comment, but I'll put some of it in here) Any help would be appreciated, as I am still relatively new to powershell

Invoke-WebRequest : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be 
null.\r\nParameter name: cloneRequestBody","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, 
mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At [locationRemoved]\testPlanCloneTool.ps1:39 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $apiUrl -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body $ ...

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: